# best way to jQuery tree traversal?

Tags: jquery, dom, tree-traversal

I got the following code:

```
<table border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>issue</td>
      <td><a class="issueDrawer" href="#">view</a></td>
      <td>description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="issueDrawer" style="display: none;"><td colspan="100%">boom!</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>issue</td>
      <td><a class="issueDrawer" href="#">view</a></td>
      <td>description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="issueDrawer" style="display: none;"><td colspan="100%">boom!</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>issue</td>
      <td><a class="issueDrawer" href="#">view</a></td>
      <td>description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="issueDrawer" style="display: none;"><td colspan="100%">boom!</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically I'm performing an action on "a.issueDrawer" which should animate "tr.issueDrawer". From "a.issueDrawer" I'm currently doing $(this).parent().parent().next(), but there must be a cleaner way to travers up and find the first "tr.issueDrawer".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.parent().parent()`, you can use [`.closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr.issueDrawer')
```